# Object Disposes Before Using Datas

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm struggling with some **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader** problems.

Actually, I made a DatabaseHandler for execute queries more convenient, with IDisposable interface for using statements.

When I use the handler for reading single article, query successfully executed, however, the handler disposed before I use data.

Then, the result is **NullReferenceException**. Here's the article reading code, and **Dispose()**.

```
// Article Reading Code
using (var ArticleHandler = new DatabaseHandler())
{
    var ArticleReader = ArticleHandler.ExecuteCommand("ARTICLE_INQUIRY",
        DatabaseHandler.QueryType.ExecuteReader,
        new DatabaseParameter[]
        {
            new DatabaseParameter("seq", Sequence)
        }) as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader; //Query Successful

    if (!ArticleReader.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/articles/list.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ArticleReader.Read(); //Data Read Successful

        CurrentArticle.title = (string)ArticleReader["title"]; //NullReferenceException ?
        CurrentArticle.category = (string)ArticleReader["category"];
        CurrentArticle.datetime = (string)ArticleReader["written_datetime"];
        CurrentArticle.content = (string)ArticleReader["content"];
    }
}


/* Database Handler Dispose() */
public void Dispose()
{
    CurrentConnection = null;
}
```

P.S. I checked column names, and they are match with database information.

Comment: why are you setting it to null?

Comment: So `CurrentArticle` is null?  - can't diagnose that with the code provided. Unrelated but If CurrentConnection is an SqlConnection you need to dispose it in your dispose() not just set it to null.

Comment: Well, **DatabaseHandler** class stores connections to `private SqlConnection CurrentConnection;`, so I thought it need to be nulled.

Comment: I think the **ArticleReader** is disposed before I use datas.

Comment: No, `ArticleReader` is likely fine else `.Read()` would fail.  `CurrentArticle` is the culprit, test and see.

Comment: I checked that `ArticleReader.Read()` returned `true`.

Comment: I declared `CurrentArticle` on current class as `protected Article CurrentArticle;`.

Comment: `Article` is class for storing informations from `ArticleReader`.

Comment: If your `CurrentConnection` is a SqlConnection, then setting it to null is not enough to correctly dispose of it. You should call it's `Dispose()` method first.

Comment: `protected Article CurrentArticle` - after this  `CurrentArticle` is still `null` in the absence of a `new`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to initialize `CurrentArticle` with `new`.... sorry ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check inside your database handler if you are closing the underlying sqlconnection before accessing the reader to access data in the next line. If the sqlconnection is getting closed, the reader will get closes automatically. Paste the handler Execute command code so we can have look at it

Comment: well, I used the handler several times, but problem occured just here. I just solved the problem. thank you for answer anyway!

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: NullReferenceException thrown when I access `CurrentArticle`. I misunderstood that  `Dispose()`occured such issues because of debugger's flow.